# Sorting a field based on several values in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an array of city codes

```
$cities=[9,12,14,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11,13]
```

My posts table has a foreign key named city_id

I want sorting posts based on the values of this array

In this way: the first posts of the city 9 then the posts of the city 12  and then posts of city 14 and etc to be loaded

I tried using this method but this is wrong

```
$posts->orderByRaw('city_id in ? desc',$cities);
```

Can you help me find the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the friends solution,I used this method, and I think it's less complicated than the suggested methods of friends

```
 $posts=$posts->orderByRaw('FIELD(city_id, '.$cities->implode( ', ').') asc')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can i think of doing something like that(at least right now) is by doing something like so

```
$all_posts = [];
$cities=[9,12,14,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11,13];

foreach ($cities as city) {
    $city_posts = Post::whereRaw('city_id = ?', $city)->orderByRaw('created_at DESC');
    array_push($all_posts, $city_posts);
}

dd($all_posts);
```

Answer (score 0):

1st find all the `posts` relevant to `cities` and then `sort` w.r.t given order like

```
$cities = [9,12,14,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11,13]; // order you'd like to see with posts

$posts = Post::whereIn('city_id', $cities)->sort(function($a, $b) uses ($cities) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a->getAttributes()['city_id'], $cities);
    $pos_b = array_search($b->getAttributes()['city_id'], $cities);
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
})->get();

// $posts contains the required order with city_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw query with "CASE something THEN index" this way you tell the query to see something as index so you can assign 0 to the first item in your array.

```
$sql .= "....";

foreach($cities as $index => $city) {
    $sql .= "CASE {$city} THEN {$index}";
}

$sql .= "....";
```